# SQLite generate series is missing when calling with python

Tags: python, sqlite

The following statement works fine when used directly in sqlite:

`SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 10);`

But when I try to use it via python sqlite3, it fails:

```
import sqlite3

c = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
c.execute("SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 10)")
```

Error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: generate_series`

Is there a different between how sqlite is called via python vs directly?

Comment: [generate_series](https://www.sqlite.org/series.html) is a loadable extension not included in the standard release of SQLite.